# Which group is isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

If I have an abelian group $G$ of order $p^n$, how can I decide if it's isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p \times\ldots \times \Bbb{Z}_p$ ($n$ times) or to $\Bbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \Bbb{Z}_p \times\ldots \times \Bbb{Z}_p$ ($n-1 $times), etc.

For example,  mean if my group is order 8, how can i decide if it's isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_8$ or to $\Bbb{Z}_2\times \Bbb{Z}_4$ or to  $\Bbb{Z}_2\times \Bbb{Z}_2\times \Bbb{Z}_2$?

Do i have to analyze the group, order of its elements and then decide or does there exist a theorem or criterion to decide it instantly?

Comment: How is the group given to you? Without more info, of course you need more information than just the order of the group, and it is abelian of order $p^n$ (unless $p=1$).

Comment: I have for example G=Aut(Zm)

Comment: m=p1^a1....pr^ar... I know is isomorph to U(Zm) that is U(Zp1^a1) x U(Zp2^a2)...x U(Zpr^ar)...

Comment: In the end i have many groups of order p^a, q^b,... With p,q... primes

Comment: So is your question actually how to figure out what group $U(\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z})$ is?(Don't edit the question to that as these are different questions) Those are abelian groups of order $p^n(p-1)$.  There might be a more explanatory method to figure out that group. You could probably search around and see, or ask another question to get that answered. (as a hint, for odd prime the group is $\mathbb{Z}/\phi(p^n) \mathbb {Z}$.)

Comment: (order $p^{n-1}(p-1)$ not $p^n(p-1)$)

Comment: why are u talking about factor group? i only meant if i have G abelian group, |G| = 16=2*2*2*2. the theorem which says Zmn is isomorph to Zm x Zn if and only if (m,n)=1 doesnt work here. So my question was if i have to see the order of the elements to understand which of groups is it isomorph (Z2 x Z2 x Z2 x Z2 , Z2 Z2 x Z4, Z4 x Z4,...etc) or if i can istantly understand it with a theorem or anything else. I think the answer is the to look at the order of elements but maybe u could enlight me :D

Comment: Factor groups is how some people write $\mathbb{Z}_m$. I thought you were wanting to know what $U(\mathbb{Z}_m)$ was by figuring out $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^n})$, but maybe I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

The most usual way would be to look at the order of the elements in your given group. Using your example where $|G| = 8$, suppose you find that $G$ contains an element of order $8$. Then $G$ must be $\newcommand{\Ints}{\mathbb{Z}} \Ints_8$ because neither $\Ints_4 \times \Ints_2$ and $\Ints_2 \times \Ints_2 \times \Ints_2$ have an element of order $8$.

Otherwise if there is no element of order $8$, but you do find an element of order $4$, then $G$ is $\Ints_4 \times \Ints_2$ because $\Ints_2 \times \Ints_2 \times \Ints_2$ has no element of order $4$.

Comment: Ok ty, so i have to look at the order of elements, see if the group is ciclic ecc ecc as i supposed. With high exponent it becomes a little hard, isnt it?